# Show custom page content

Tags: php, message, inbox

First thanks all for helping.

I'm trying to show custom content on inbox page. My code looks like that:

```
 <?php 
$page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ($page == 'messages' || $page == "/" || $page == 'inbox') {
?>
@if ($buttons or $showSearchBox)
<div class="toolbar top">
    {!! $buttons !!}

    @if ($showSearchBox)
        <div class="model-search-box">
    @if (user()->countMessages() > 0)
        <div class="inbox-notify">
    You have unread messages, please read that!
    </div>
    @endif
            {!! Form::open(['url' => URL::current().'/search']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('search', $searchString, array('placeholder'=>'Search in messages ), ['class' => 'search-string']) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit(trans('app.search'), ['class' => 'button-search']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    @endif
  </div>
@endif
    <?php } ?>
```

But this code works only on "messages/inbox" page. How can i too add this content on "messages/outbox" page? Sorry for bad english. I'm newbiee on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
    $page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($page == 'messages' || $page == "/" || $page == 'inbox' || $page == 'outbox') {
    ?>
    @if ($buttons or $showSearchBox)
    <div class="toolbar top">
        {!! $buttons !!}

        @if ($showSearchBox)
            <div class="model-search-box">
        @if (user()->countMessages() > 0)
            <div class="inbox-notify">
        You have unread messages, please read that!
        </div>
        @endif
                {!! Form::open(['url' => URL::current().'/search']) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('search', $searchString, array('placeholder'=>'Search in messages ), ['class' => 'search-string']) !!}
                        {!! Form::submit(trans('app.search'), ['class' => 'button-search']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        @endif
      </div>
    @endif
        <?php } ?>
```